# Difficulties with Minted and UTF-8

Tags: unicode, minted

I'm trying to typeset Python programs with LaTeX and the Minted package. I'm under Ubuntu 15.10, with TeXlive installed from Ubuntu standard repositories. The python-pygment package is at version 2.0.1+dfsg-1. Compiling the code below :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{minted}
% \setminted{encoding=utf-8}

\begin{document}
On importe toute la librairie Tkinter (attention, cette écriture ne fonctionne qu'en Python 3)
\begin{minted}{python}
from tkinter import *

# Creation de la fenetre de base de l'application
f=Tk()
# On lui donne un nom
f.title("Découverte de Tkinter")
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

ends up with the following error :

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�co not set up for use with LaTeX. 
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              
l.7 ...dq{}D�couverte de Tkinter\PYZdq{}}\PY{p}{)}
```

If I change the « é » in the string into a simple « e », it compiles silently. I've read somewhere it could be useful to set the encoding or outencoding parameter, but I get another error :

```
(./Python-Tkinter.w18)))/usr/bin/pygmentize
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \setminted 
l.7 \setminted
              {encoding=utf-8}
?
```

I checked the /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted/minted.sty file (which is at version 2015/01/31 v2.0) :

```
user@machine:/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted# cat minted.sty | grep -E 'encoding|setminted'
    \ifx\encodingdefault\upquote@OTone
\minted@def@optcl{encoding}{-P encoding}{#1}
\minted@def@optcl{outencoding}{-P outencoding}{#1}
\newcommand{\minted@encoding}{\minted@get@opt{encoding}{UTF8}}
          %Need a version of open() that supports encoding under Python 2
            f = open(\"}#1\detokenize{\", \"r\", encoding=\"}\minted@encoding\detokenize{\");
            f = open(\"}\minted@outputdir\jobname.pyg\detokenize{\", \"w\", encoding=\"}\minted@encoding\detokenize{\");
        %Need a version of open() that supports encoding under Python 2
          f = open(\"}#1\detokenize{\", \"r\", encoding=\"}\minted@encoding\detokenize{\");
          f = open(\"}\minted@outputdir\jobname.pyg\detokenize{\", \"w\", encoding=\"}\minted@encoding\detokenize{\");
\newcommand{\setminted}[2][]{%
\newcommand{\setmintedinline}[2][]{%
\setmintedinline[php]{startinline=true}
\newcommand{\usemintedstyle}[2][]{\setminted[#1]{style=#2}}
    \setminted{style=default}%
```

Following an advice, here is the output from command line compilation with the \listfiles command :

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
   babel.sty    2014/09/25 3.9l The Babel package
 frenchb.ldf    2015/06/26 v3.1g French support from the babel system
scalefnt.sty    
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
  minted.sty    2011/09/17 v1.7 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX
fancyvrb.sty    2008/02/07
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
ifplatform.sty    2010/10/22 v0.4 Testing for the operating system
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
catchfile.sty    2011/03/01 v1.6 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
testMinted.w18
supp-pdf.mkii
testMinted.pyg
testMinted.out.pyg
  t1cmtt.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
 ***********
```

So everything seems OK. I'm stuck. It would be great if someone had an idea. Thanks.

Comment: It works for me without error in texlive 2015, make sure that your file is saved as utf8

Comment: Thanks for answering. My file is saved as UTF-8. I'm on a native UTF-8 system. I usually compiles UTF-8 files without any problem. The present problem is related to the use of the Minted package...

Comment: I get [this output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xkKUz.png) from your example

Comment: Oh I do believe you, don't be afraid ;) ! Thus should I move to original TeXlive ? It's a pain to update, I'm trying to keep the maintenance of my system as simple as possible...

Comment: I don't see anything particularly that's changed recently, add \listfiles to your example and post the resulting file list from the log can compare package versions

Comment: Your log is showing U+FFFD as the character not set up for use with LaTeX, that is the "Replacement (non) character"  which is strongly indicative of an encoding error. Latex isn't seeing the `é` at all.

Comment: I updated the main post with the list you wanted. I ensure you that there is no encodinbg mistake. I'm under an UTF-8 system, I use standard tools that do standard job. I shifted to a simple text editor (Gedit) and created a new file : same problem. I shifted to Geany, where I reloaded the file « as an Unicode > UTF-8 » file, then I overwrote the file, same problem.

Comment: I copy-pasted the output from my terminal, hence this odd character I suppose. I've installed TeXlive 2015 on another computer, which runs Ubuntu 14.04. I also have an error :
*** Error while highlighting:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 112: invalid continuation byte
   (file "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode).
But pygmentize -V says I'm at version 1.6 on this computer (not 2.0.1 as on the 1st PC).

Comment: well there you go: 0xe9 is an e acute in latin1, not utf8 encoding. the file is not in utf8

Comment: I don't think so. On the 2nd computer I used TeXmaker, which claims to be in UTF-8 mode (bottom right of the status bar). I use a file without accent, the command-line tool  « file » says the file is in ASCII text. Then I turn a « e » into a « é », « file » now says the file is in UTF-8 unicode text. And I get the previous error. If i remove the minted environment (and the comment beginning with #, of course), LaTeX compiles the file without any error (*with* the *utf8* inputenc). So, NO, I'm not in ISO-8859-1(5), but it seems that the Python tool « thinks » I am...

Comment: To be sure I converted to UTF-8 the file you think encoded in ISO-8859-15 with iconv : the é is turned into Ā©. And the compilation fails with « undefined control sequence » error. I'm really lost... Thanks for helping, anyway.

Comment: minted is a bit newer here (well several things are but) `minted.sty    2015/09/09 v2.1 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX`

Comment: Ā© is what you see if you look at the bytes of the utf8 encoding as latin1 characters.

Comment: I can reproduce the error with TeX Live 2013 but not TeX Live 2014 or 2015.

Comment: Which operating system do you use ?

Comment: The minted version you’re using explicitly only supports XeLaTeX and LuaTeX, not pdfLaTeX, with UTF-8. Upgrade your minted installation to change this, or switch to XeLaTeX or LuaTeX for *proper* Unicode support.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm going to give LuaTeX a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally succeeded in compiling my document (with UTF-8 characters inside code). I had to remove the TeXlive proposed in Ubuntu standard repositories and install TeXlive 2015. This works with one of my computers running under Ubuntu 15.10.

**But the problem remains unsolved with my other computer, which runs with Ubuntu 14.04.** Here the python-pygments package is at version 1.6, and I think this is where the problem lies (I updated TeXlive 2015 - not TeXlive from repos - to its latest state before).

I also tried to update the python-pygments package with one backported from Ubuntu 15.10 (v. 2.0.1), but this breaks some things (eg : pygmentize does not work anymore).

If someone had an idea about this... Thanks in advance.

---

Update : according to the penultimate comment of my question, I'm going to give LuaTeX a try. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve that (same) problem by using the *lualatex*-command instead of *pdflatex* for compiling. LuaLatex is Unicode-capable, so you (just) have to take care of two things in your TeX-file(s):

- comment out the line where you import/configure the *inputenc*-Package:

  ```
  %\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  ```
- rebuild the whole document/project
  (for example in TexStudio there are two Buttons: "*rebuild & view*" and "*compile*". 
  Just compiling e.g. wouldn't  create a new Table of Contents , so *lualatex* would use the old **.toc*-file - and could run into encoding errors there.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.